# JEditable Returning an Incorrect Response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jeditable

I am using JEditable jquery plugin to update some data on my webpage. One field is behaving strangely. Instead of the usual replacement in the cell with the new data I get something like this:

```
EM29UPDATE NetLog           
SET  grid  = 'EM29', latitude='', longitude='' WHERE recordID = '468'
```

If I look at the MySQL DB table it was updated correctly. And when I refresh the page it looks fine. I've done no customizing to JEditable and all the other edits on the page work just fine. Latitude and Longitude are on the DB but they are not editable fields on the page. In fact they don't even appear on the page.

Anyone have a thought why this is happening?

Comment: plugin url and a fiddle to play with would be great.

Comment: Take a look at http://kcmecc.org/graphics/RaspPi/index.php select # 1 from the drop down.

Comment: seems like the response of your save request contains the query & hence, JEditable replaces the cell value with the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JEditable replaces the value with the response of the save request. It seems like in your case the save request is returning the SQL update query & hence, it shows up in the cell.

Check your php script to make sure it's not outputting/returning anything else than the newValue.

In order to see the response of the request, you can use chrome developer tools. For example :

1. Open http://kcmecc.org/graphics/RaspPi/index.php
2. Select #1 from the dropdown
3. Open developer tools (press F12)
4. Go to the Network tab
5. Edit any cell in the table & hit ENTER
6. Notice the request being sent in XHR/All filter
7. Click on the request & then select the Response tab to see the value of the response sent by the server for the save query.

[image]
References :

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-panel-overview

Comment: Yes, I love Chrome's ability to show this all to me. I've never used the XHR thing before so thanks for that. But why is only this one column doing this. You would think they all would.

Comment: Anything can happen, you might have certain conditions/checks in code for that column, an entire different code path might execute for that particular column. What does chrome say ? what is the response for that columns' save request ?

Comment: EM29UPDATE NetLog
   SET  grid  = 'EM29', latitude='', longitude='' WHERE recordID = '468'

Comment: just as I said it, the backend is sending that response, hence that needs further debugging on where is the query bring printed. It's not related to JEditable sending the wrong response, which works as expected.

Comment: There you lose me. I don't really know much about how JEditable works.  http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Comment: well, in the context of this question, you don't really need to know how it works, just make sure the save-column http ajax request sends only the updatedValue not the complete query.

Comment: I think I see where my problem lies. I just need to open my eyes sometimes. The save.php has code in it that is causing the problem. I think. You showed me the answer with the XHR/All stuff. I had never used it before. Your are definitely not a "coding-idiot" thank you so much for the help. I'll re-post if I still can't figure it out.

Comment: you can accept the answer if it helped you figure out.